# Getting empty index value in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

1. Please support me in this code that it always print out null values after processing all things.
2. I got null values with empty index value([])

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe'
s=Service('C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe' )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = s)
driver.maximize_window()
url='https://www.linkedin.com/login?'
driver.get(url)
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")))
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys('ndy.andupa@gmail.com')
password.send_keys('*******')
login=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']"))).click()
searching=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Search']")))
searching.send_keys('software engineering manager')
searching.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
profile_list=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//li[@class='reusable-search__result-container']")
pr_list=[]
for prof in profile_list:
    name=prof.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[class='app-aware-link'] span  span[aria-hidden]")
    print(name.text)
    pr_list.append(name.text)
    time.sleep(3)
print(pr_list)
```

Comment: I would recommend to use another name than list, since it is a builtin. Also could you print name instead of called and list? And paste the output?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction ! I've changed all the thing you recommended and i get  empty index([]) value when i tried to print name.text also.

Comment: Could you add the following to your post: The html of the page and the output from the terminal?

Comment: LinkedIn tries to recognize scraping code. See I.e. https://blog.linkedin.com/2021/july/15/linkedin-safety-series-what-is-scraping